# Notify activity from adapter when item is deleted (emptyView)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

Let's define one variable in the begin, it will be more easier to read:
sqlite3 column `KEY_TITLE` = `A`

I have activity in conduction with cursor loader. When there are no rows in column `A` I want activity to display an emptyView. To do that, I created a method which checks all rows in column `A` if there is any data in it.

```
fun hideLayout(){
        val isEmpty = emptyViewObserver(applicationContext).isEmpty()
        if (isEmpty) {
            recyclerView.visibility = View.GONE
            emptyView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            emptyView.visibility = View.GONE
        }

    }
```

class `emptyViewObserver` with `isEmpty` method:

```
 class emptyViewObserver(val context: Context){

        fun isEmpty():Boolean{
            val db = WalletDbHelper(context).readableDatabase
            val projection = arrayOf(KEY_TITLE)

            val cursor = db.query(
                    WalletEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                    projection,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null
            )

            val names = mutableListOf<String>()
            with(cursor){
                while (moveToNext()){
                    val name = getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(WalletEntry.KEY_TITLE))
                    names.add(name)
                }
            }
            db.close()
            return names.isEmpty()
        }
    }
```

Whenever I perform any CRUD operation in `MainActivity` class I call `hideLayout` method to check out if emptyView should be shown or not. It works fine. But I'm facing problem after I perform delete operation from my adapter to call `hideLayout()` method. For obvious reasons it throws me error when calling it directly from adapter so I though about implementing interface and overriding this in `MainActivity`. I read some tutorials but I still didn't figure out how to implement this properly.

This is my delete method from adapter:

```
holder.delete.setOnClickListener { v ->
            val popup = PopupMenu(context, v)
            val inflater = popup.menuInflater
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.delete, popup.menu)
            popup.show()
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener { v ->
              when(v.itemId) {
                  R.id.delete -> {
                      delete(uri, walletName)
                      true
              }
                  else -> {
                      false
                  }
              }
            }
        }
```

and delete():

```
fun delete(uri: String, walletName: String){
        val newUri: Uri = Uri.parse(uri)
        context.contentResolver.delete(newUri, WalletEntry.KEY_TITLE, arrayOf(walletName))
    }
```

Do you have any ideas how can I write this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a callback, When you delete some item, check if is the last one and if it is true call that.

Add this interface on your adapter:

```
interface OnListIsEmpty{
    fun onListIsEmpty()
}
```

And create a object of this like global variable in your adapter too:

```
private var mOnListIsEmpty: OnListIsEmpty? = null
```

Add a setter method:

```
fun setOnListIsEmpty(onListIsEmpty: OnListIsEmpty){
    this.mOnListIsEmpty = onListIsEmpty
}
```

And in your delete method do the validation if is empty if it is true then:

```
    mOnListIsEmpty?.onListIsEmpty()
```

And not forget set the callback when you initilize the adapter with:

```
adapter.setOnListIsEmpty(object : OnListIsEmpty{
        override fun onListIsEmpty() {
            //your action
        }
    })
```